# CakePHP で not を複数つなげる方法

Tags: php, cakephp

`Model.col1` に `ほげ` が含まれていない

そして

`Model.col2` に `ふが` が含まれていないもの

を取得する時の `conditions` の書き方を教えて下さい。

|col1|col2|取得|
|---|---|---|
|ほげ|ふが|しない|
|ほげ|もげ|しない|
|もげ|ふが|しない|
|もげ|もげ|する|

Answer (score 1):

condition のカラム名に直接 NOT を記述します。
以下、`SamplesController` 上で `Model` というモデルを使ったときの例です.

```
$this->loadModel('Model');
$params = array
(
    'conditions' => array
    (
        'col1 NOT ' => 'ほげ',
        'col2 NOT ' => 'ふげ',
    )
);

$return = $this->Model->find('all',$params);
```